# Facebook Share doesn't update data content

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, share

So the problem is this, I've added some share buttons, to share each video I post on my website. It really doesn't share the video thumbnail, but the main content I want to share is the text inside the div.

So I added a few share buttons to share the URL something like this: `www.mywebsite.com/#video1` It will share this URL and it displays the text inside the div `#video1`

The problem is that now I added another video, added the same code with id `#video4`and it doesn't display the text inside, in fact when the pop-up share window appears, it display the site title. Now I noticed it doesn't update data when I edit other texts that it would share correctly.

Basically, my problem is that the facebook share is not updating data to share properly with the right content.

```
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="video1">
      <div class="info">
           <h2 class="title">Text to share</h2>
      </div>

      <div class="fb-share-button" data-layout="button" data-href="http://www.mywebsite.com/#video1"></div>
</div>
```

This is sharing but not displaying the proper content, it's not parsing (the title atleast).

And yes, I have the facebook script added to my code.

Any ideas?

Comment: URLs that only differ in the hash part are _not_ seen as individual Open Graph objects. You need a unique URL for each video you want to share, and that URL has to deliver the OG meta data for that video.

Comment: And how could I possibly do it? I wanted the videos in tabs, as I have them.
And why did my share buttons of the first 3 video tabs share their title?
Thanks for your answer.